# File Tokens Will Not Print Correctly

Tags: c

Ok so this is probably a classic problem and I'm sorry for bringing this back to here. I am tokenizing a file and everything seems to be fine. When I print the file, it is only printing the last 2 tokens that I am grabbing. I have tried Googling this issue but I am not good enough at Google searches to narrow the results down to this very specific problem. A link to a solution would be very helpful...

```
artist_in = fopen("artist.txt", "r");
    cd_in = fopen("cd.txt", "r");
    track_in = fopen("track.txt", "r");

    if (artist_in == NULL || cd_in == NULL || track_in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: did not successully open files\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Successfully opened files\n");
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, artist_in) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(buffer, DELIMS);
        while(token != NULL) {
            artistTokens[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, DELIMS);
            tokenCount++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", artistTokens[i]);
    }
```

output is:

```
Successfully opened files
4
Melanie C
4
Melanie C
4
Melanie C
4
Melanie C
```

file contains:

```
1|Pink Floyd
2|Genesis
3|Einaudi
4|Melanie C
```

Delimiter being used is `'|'`

This is making me bang my head. I am not too familiar with just pure C. I can easily do this in C++. Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: Who/what is 'Einaudi'?  Are they any good?

Comment: I have no clue. haha. This is just some file provided to me to populate a song database table with. These are the artists

Comment: If all of  your files open successfully why are you printing to `stderr`?

Comment: `artistTokens[i++] = token;` :  `token` point to part of `buffer`. You need make clone. E.g `artistTokens[i++] = strdup(token);`

Comment: I'm not sure if saving the pointers from a strtok() scan will work.

Comment: lol @BLUEPIXY thinks not :)

Comment: You should be copying the data to somewhere: the `token` pointer you save gets overwritten from one line to the next.

Comment: the present logic of call `fopen()` for all three files, then checking if the calls were successful has the problem that the reason for any failure is lost by the next call to `fopen()`  suggest following this format:  `if( !fopen(...) ) { perror( "fopen for ... failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }   etc  Then the system message as to why the fopen failed will also be output.  That way, the results will be much more useful.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I will definitely change my naive implementation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same `buffer` for each line of the file, so each time you read a new line, the tokens on that line will overwrite the tokens from the previous line. Use `strdup()` to make copies of the tokens.

```
artistTokens[i++] = strdup(token);
```

Since this performs dynamic allocation using `malloc()`, you'll need to free them when you're done with the tokens.

Comment: omg im an idiot! lol :( Thank you very much. Geez, i can't believe I didn't realize this

Comment: So I will have to go through my array of char*'s and free each char* pointer that I duped, thats what you are saying right? I know if C++ that when you start pushing things to the heap with arrays of pointers you will need to loop through them and delete.

Comment: That's correct, you'll need to free each element of `artistTokens`.